# Writing a regex expression

Tags: regex

How do I write a regex expression starting with A and the second through fourth characters in the string must be digits and the fifth character must be a lowercase letter?

```
/[A | B | C]{2-4}[a-z]/
```

Sorry I am just not getting it, but that's my go at it

Comment: How does B and C fit in to what you're trying to do? Either way, `[A | B | C]` means the characters "A", "B", "C", " " and "|". `{2-4}` matches the literal text "{2-4}"; you probably meant `{2,4}`, although that doesn't help solve your problem.

Comment: You should practice a bit at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uO4eK5/1) for example

Comment: Reading a manual might help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tushar said, his solution should work. Here's an explanation the parts involved.

`^A\d{3}[a-z]$`

- `^` the start of the string
- `A` a literal "A" character
- `\d` any digit (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
- `{3}` the previous part is repeated exactly 3 times (any digit, then any digit, then any digit)
- `[a-z]` any character in the set. in this case it's a range from lowercase "a" to lowercase "z", which will also match all characters in the alphabet in between
- `$` the end of the string

A good place to start learning is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).